# How to change date format of magento 2 admin grid filter without using ui component?

Tags: magento2, admin, filter, uicomponent, date

Below is `some_grid_block.xml` ,

**How can I change date format in calendar filter.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.qrcode.grid.container">
            <block class="Oneteam\Qrcode\Block\Grid" name="adminhtml.qrcode.grid" as="grid">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">QrcodeGrid</argument>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Oneteam\Qrcode\Model\ResourceModel\Qrcode\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">qr_id</argument>
                    <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Date">
                    <filterRange name="created_at"  class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Date">
                        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                        <filterDate name="from">
                            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                                    <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">dd/MM/YYYY</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </filterDate>
                        <filterDate name="to">
                            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                                    <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">dd/MM/YYYY</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                        </filterDate>
                    </filterRange>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="qrcode.grid.columnSet">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">QrcodeGrid</argument>
                        <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="generatorClass" xsi:type="string">Magento\Backend\Model\Widget\Grid\Row\UrlGenerator</item>
                            <item name="path" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                            <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="qr_id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="qr_id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">true</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">qr_id</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="qr_code">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">QR Code</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">qr_code</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>

                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="qr_status">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">QR Code Status</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">qr_status</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="binggz_value">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Number of Binggz</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">binggz_value</argument>
                            <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Oneteam\Qrcode\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Binggz</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>

                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="customer_username">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">customer_username</argument>
                            <argument name="escape" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="created_date">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created Date</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">date</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">created_date</argument>
                            <argument name="format" xsi:type="string" translate="true">dd-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>

                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 15):

Following is the XML configuration that should work as you intended:

```
<filterRange name="created_at" class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="date" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd/MM/y</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="outputDateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd/MM/y</item>
                    <item name="inputDateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd/MM/y</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</filterRange>
```

Some information on the above configuration:

- `dateFormat` (in `options`) is the format that is input into the filter field from the Date Picker.
- `inputDateFormat` is the format of the date that comes from the server
- `outputDateFormat` is the format of the date that is sent to the server.

Depending on how the date is formatted, you may not need `inputDateFormat`, although, I'm not sure it would hurt to have it. If you set `dateFormat`, you will probably need to set `inputDateFormat` as well due to the way the filters are handled.

Also, notice the use of the `y` instead of `YYYY` for the year. The date component uses the [ICU Date Format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

---

#### Background

If you are interested in how the nested configuration actually gets to where it needs to go, these are the steps. All of the following apply to values inside of the `defaults: {}` object of the Javascript class. The file paths are relative to: `/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/`

1. In `grid/filters/range.js` there is a `templates` option.
2. Inside `templates` is `date` which contains configuration for the `date.js` form element.
3. The `form/element/date.js` class checks it's `options` value to see if `dateFormat` is set.
4. `outputDateFormat` and `inputDateFormat` are both used in the `date.js` form element.

---

Finally, when you mentioned that you didn't want to use a UI Component, I am assuming that your goal was to avoid extending Javascript classes, or some version of that. The `filterRange` XML node is configuration for a UI Component so it does actually use a UI Component.

Answer (score 0):

to change the date format follow this steps

In grid/filters/range.js there is a templates option.
Inside templates is date which contains configuration for the date.js form element.
The form/element/date.js class checks it's options value to see if dateFormat is set.
outputDateFormat and inputDateFormat are both used in the date.js form element.