# How to change date format for backend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, xml, uicomponent, date

On **Order-Sales** tab  we have **Filters**.
Here  we have **Purchase Date** which it's a date picker, and by default, the date format it's mm/dd/yy. [image]

I want to make this date filed to be dd/mm/yy but i can't find any solution.
The only thing that i found it's this xml: `sales_order_grid.xml` located in `module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component` wich have this lines responsabile for that filed:

```
 <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Purchase Date</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY, H:MM:SS A</item>
                </item>
            </argument>'
```

Here i have this line `<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY, H:MM:SS A</item>`. If i change this in DD MM, YYY nothing happend.
I already change the date format form backend settings to dd/mm/yyy and nothing happend

Does anyone know how can i change this date format? or it's another way to do this except this xml?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151253/how-to-change-date-format-of-magento-2-admin-grid-filter-without-using-ui-compon