# UI component - display the time to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format(ISO time format)

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, time

I create some admin listing pages by UI component, the **default time format** in their time column all like below

[image: default time format]

The UI component codes like below

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

The time format **in database is right**(ISO time format), that is what I want to display.

[image]

So, how to display the time to "**Y-m-d H:i:s**" format(ISO time format) in UI component? Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Since you have any questions, feel free to contact me. I’ll try to help you.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thank you very much :) Your answer is already working, accept and up vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to change the `dateFormat` value of your column:

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Default format could be fount inside the Date column component `magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/date.js`

```
return Column.extend({
    defaults: {
        dateFormat: 'MMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss A'
    },
...
```

**Update:**

> Also, notice the use of the y instead of YYYY for the year. The date component uses the [ICU Date Format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

[Source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151253/how-to-change-date-format-of-magento-2-admin-grid-filter-without-using-ui-compon)

So, format should slightly different. I think this one could be suitable:

```
<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add date format **`dateFormat`** value of the column as **YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss**, [the ICU date time format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

Take a look at below link for more detail:

> http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

**M month in year**

> **M       9**
>
> **MM       09**
>
> **MMM       Sep**
>
> **MMMM     September**
>
> **MMMMM     S**

**d day in month**

> **dd                    02**

**And YYYY for year**

So the date format line of code is:

```
<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</item>
```

You can try below code for your date column and data:

```
<column name="purchase_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item> 
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm a</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
 </column>
```

Comment: i want to display only the date using modifier, but it is not working

Comment: <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">YYYY-MM-dd</item>
Did you try with above line of code?