# Set date format in admin grid

Tags: grid, uicomponent, magento2.2.2

I have create a ui-component grid in magento2 .I need to set the default symbol (if the end date is empty in that field) like -- for **End**  column in grid

```
<column name="date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From Date</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </column>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

[image]

Thanks

> Array (
>       [post_id] => 5
>       [publish_time] => 2018-11-21 06:13:24
>       [from_date] => 2018-11-21 05:30:00
>       [to_date] => --
>       [is_active] => 1     )

Comment: Can you please explain more or add screenshot?

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Not working ...

Comment: Please check your field name should be "date" in database.

Comment: I have changed that but not working

Comment: Can you please print $dataSource['data']['items'] and give me output of one fields records from array ? and yes you need to flush cache after change in xml.

Comment: to_date field should be null.still, you can add condition like this : if(strtotime($v['date']) < 0 || if(strtotime($v['date']) == ""){){

Answer (score 4):

You can change the format of the date. Add this line to your code

```
<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
```

modify  the date format according to you . For more reference check this link
[UI component - display the time to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format(ISO time format)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204506/ui-component-display-the-time-to-y-m-d-his-formatiso-time-format)

Comment: I need to add  symbol ' - - ' if the date is empty in that field

Comment: How to achieve the same in Grid.php block ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom file to add customization :

```
<column name="date" class="VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TestingFile">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From Date</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Create File at `VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TestingFile.php`

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class TestingFile extends Column {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as $r => $v) {
                if(strtotime($v['date']) < 0){
                    $dataSource['data']['items'][$r]['date'] = "-----";
                } else{
                    $dataSource['data']['items'][$r]['date'] = date('Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', strtotime($v['date']));
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: same issue its not working for me

Comment: How to achieve the same in Grid.php block ?