# How to change date format of yyyy-mm-dd for dd-mm-yyyy on admin grid?

Tags: magento2, grid, xml, custom-column-grid, custom-admin-grid

Hi i'm new at magento 2 and i want to change the date format on admin grid of yyyy-mm-dd for dd-mm-yyyy.
[image: date comlumn]

[image: date column code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format of the date. Add this line to your code

```
<item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</item>
```

Modify the date format according to you . For more reference check this link ---

**[UI component - display the time to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format(ISO time format)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204506/ui-component-display-the-time-to-y-m-d-his-formatiso-time-format)**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...