# how to translate the date in the grid

Tags: magento2

I have a problem i want to translate the date data in the column grid (for example : from 03 April 2020 00:00:00 to 03 Avril 2020 00:00:00) , but it's not translated even if I set the attribute 'translate=true'

Ps : this problem is related to upgrade from Magento 2.2 to 2.3

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date"
                component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Order Date</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

this is the class Date.php in Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns

```
public function prepare()
    {
        $config = $this->getData('config');
        $config['filter'] = [
            'filterType' => 'dateRange',
            'templates' => [
                'date' => [
                    'options' => [
                        'dateFormat' => $this->timezone->getDateFormatWithLongYear(),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $localeData = $this->dataBundle->get($this->locale);
        /** @var \ResourceBundle $monthsData */
        $monthsData = $localeData['calendar']['gregorian']['monthNames'];
        $months = array_values(iterator_to_array($monthsData['format']['wide']));
        $monthsShort = array_values(
            iterator_to_array(
                null !== $monthsData->get('format')->get('abbreviated')
                    ? $monthsData['format']['abbreviated']
                    : $monthsData['format']['wide']
            )
        );

        $config['storeLocale'] = $this->locale;
        $config['calendarConfig'] = [
            'months' => $months,
            'monthsShort' => $monthsShort,
        ];
        if (!isset($config['dateFormat'])) {
            $config['dateFormat'] = $this->timezone->getDateTimeFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM);
        }
        $this->setData('config', $config);

        parent::prepare();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item[$this->getData('name')])) {
                    $date = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($item[$this->getData('name')]));
                    $timezone = isset($this->getConfiguration()['timezone'])
                        ? $this->booleanUtils->convert($this->getConfiguration()['timezone'])
                        : true;
                    if (!$timezone) {
                        $date = new \DateTime($item[$this->getData('name')]);
                    }
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/204509/85907

Comment: is this question related to translate date , from English to french for example or just date format