# Change date format from Calendar Widget magento 2.2.1

Tags: filter, magento-2.2.1, dateformat

I want to change the date format of admin grid filters to "dd/mm/yy" format, but I could not make it work, I try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151253/how-to-change-date-format-of-magento-2-admin-grid-filter-without-using-ui-compon) solution unsuccessful, the xml files are different in 2.2.1 magento version.

I have noticed that when the locale configurations setted with date format in "dd/mm/yy", all the widget calendars in forms, get the configuration, but the filter forms, in grids, still with "mm/dd/yy" format, which is not compatible with the locale configurations, so, how can I change the filter date field format?

Thanks in advance.